# Как разбить одномерный массив вида слово-перевод в двумерный? С#

Tags: c#

Есть файл, в котором лежат строки вида "слово-перевод". Разделителем в данном случае работает "-". Мне нужно перевести одномерный массив в двумерный таким образом, чтобы в первой его строке лежали только слова, а во второй - только перевод. Третий час мучаюсь с Split, не получается чегой-то, то одна ошибка, то вторая

Comment: В таких случаях уточняют что за ошибки. Не компилится или ошибки во время выполнения?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                temp[i, 0] = arr[i].Split(new char[] { '*' });
            }, тут у меня temp - массив двумерный, arr - одномерный. Если что, в C# я чайник полный, пришёл с С++...

Comment: ну split возвращает массив, значит надо тоже по индексам значения брать temp[i, 0] = arrRank1[i].Split(new char[] { '*' })[0]; temp[i, 1] = arrRank1[i].Split(new char[] { '*' })[1]

Comment: Необработанное исключение типа "System.NullReferenceException" в GFD.exe

Comment: Тогда тебе поможет это https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изи способ такой, если можно Linq

```
string[] arrRank1 = File.ReadAllLines("1.txt");
string[][] arrRank2 = arrRank1.Select(line => line.Split('-')).ToArray();
```

Comment: Можно немножко подробнее, если не сложно? var arrRank2 - это переменная, правильно? Её значение заносить в двумерный массив?

Comment: строка читается слева направо. var - создать переменную типа, который возвращает последняя функция ToArray() (просто лень писать string[,]  arrRank2 =)

Comment: Далее в методе Select каждая строка массива arrRank сплитится, возвращая перечисление массивов из двух элементов "до символа разделения, после символа". ToArray - конвертируем перечисление  в массив.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Разобрался, понял, в дальнейшем, надеюсь, подобных проблем не возникнет)

Comment: Лучше используйте `File.ReadLines`, тем более раз уж все равно Linq'ом проходитесь

Comment: Я проставил Вам типы, так как заметил, что ни ТС, ни Вы сами точно не знаете, что именно скрывается под `var`. Не знаю, насколько принципиально ТС нужен двумерный массив, но Вы ему таки подсунули зубчатый :)